# Android loadLibrary .so calling methods and constructor

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, shared-libraries, native

I've checked here and it seems to be no answer for my particular question. I got to know that I one can use C .so library and refer the methods in it by somewhat overriding the library native methods like below:

```
@SuppressWarnings("JniMissingFunction")
    public class MyNativeMethods {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("libraryWithSoExtension");
}
public native boolean init();
}
```

My probelem is that I'd like to call the constructor in this lib. The lib contains only couple of classes, where each of them contains 1 or 2 methods. I see from here:

[How to call methods on .so library in Android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34694398/how-to-call-methods-on-so-library-in-android-studio)

that I do not need any h, c or jni (do I really?).

Questions:

1. Could you confirm that I do not need any JNI files to access native methods from .so file?
2. Can one actually access a constructor as described above and how does the importing work if it's possible
3. MAVEN/GRADLE - Is it correct that a  will not work for .so file? And it's equivalent in gradle also?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Create JNI wrapper code and export it using extern "C". Call you C based code and inside it refer to C++ one. E.g. create C++ objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a prebuilt **.so** file that implements some native methods, you don't need its sources to build your project in Android Studio.

The catch is that the names of native methods and classes that contain these methods are hardcoded, e.g. `Java_com_example_test_MainActivity_stringFromJNI` exported function in a shared library **libmy.so** is fit to

```
package com.example.test;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  static {
    System.loadLibrary("my");
  }
  public native String stringFromJNI();
}
```

and not some other Java class or method *(there are tools to make such reverse engineering harder)*.

You can use the [javah](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javah.html) command to generate C declarations for your native methods, but it cannot reverse engineer the Java class that fits given library. But it will let you declare a native constructor, if you really want one.

Gradle plugin for Android Studio will pack the **so** files from `src/main/jniLibs` into your APK, unless you set a different **jniLibs.srcDir** directory in your **build.gradle**.

Comment: thanks. I guess I need to write a CPP class with my own JNI and include the h file in it. (which I have, I just don't have the c file) It's very tricky as this is my first contact with C/C++. What do you mean by "use javah to generate C declarations for my native methods" ? What will that give me? A C version of my Java file? Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: **javah** can give you .h and .c files that contain 'boilerplate' for the native methods declared in your Java file(s).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this is what you are looking for, but take a look here:

https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo025

you will find there super simple code with C++ being called via JNI wrapper from Java.

Comment: Thanks... this is for plain java, I see you don't use naming convention as posted by @Alex Cohn in the answer above. Isn't it a must?